# Feign Client + Consul + Ribbon - HTTPS

Tags: docker, https, spring-cloud, ribbon, feign

I have the following setup (everything as docker containers):

1. Two web services running on HTTPS mode (self-signed certificate).
2. The web services are registered in consul.
3. Web service 1 calls web service 2 using feign client.
4. web service 2 is named `authentication-service`.
5. The docker containers `cacerts` were updated to include the self-signed certificate, however, the certificate does not have the IP address because they are dynamically generated by docker.

```
@FeignClient(name = "authentication-service")
public interface AuthenticationClient extends AuthenticationApi {
}
```

When web service 1 calls web service 2 Ribbon internally is using docker's IP address. (the problem)

Moreover, It is not clear to me why feign is using HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS.

`feign.RetryableException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 172.20.0.10 found executing  POST http://authentication-service/api/auth/authenticate`

What am I missing?
How should I overcome this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you either need to install the certificates into the jre or setup the HTTP client to know about the certificates.

Comment: Hi, @spencergibb, the certificates are installed in the cacerts. However, the certificate do not include `-ext san=ip:<IP_ADDRESS>`. I'll update the question to mention that.

Comment: not installed in the docker container but the jre

Comment: yes, the certificate is installed in the jre within the docker container.